# Lightning web component querySelector return Proxy Object

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a problem with my lwc, when I try to get the tag of HTML with this.template.querySelector just return to me "proxy" object, someone can help me to solve this problem and get the information of that object or tell me what is the right way to do this, thanks.

I will show you my code.

**HTML**

```
  <lightning-card title="Commissions">
    <lightning-combobox name="famProd" value={famValue} options={famOptions} onchange={handleChangeFamily}>
    </lightning-combobox>
    <form>
      <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
        <thead>
          <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Product Name</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Product Family</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Close Date">Opportunity team</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">Commission</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <template for:each={dataToShow} for:item="item" for:index="index">
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={item.Id} data-key={item.Id}>
              <td data-label="Product">
                <div class="slds-truncate">{item.Product}</div>
              </td>
              <td data-label="Family">
                <div class="slds-truncate">{item.Family}</div>
              </td>
              <td data-label="Opp team">
                <lightning-combobox name="progress" value={value} placeholder="Choose user" options={options}
                  required="true">
                </lightning-combobox>
              </td>
              <td data-label="Commission">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="20%">
                  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-fixed-addon">
                    <span class="slds-form-element__addon">%</span>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Insert commission"
                      aria-labelledby="fixed-text-label fixed-text-addon-pre fixed-text-addon-post" class="slds-input"
                      value={item.Comission} min="1" max="100" required onchange={onchangeCell}/>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
        <lightning-button-group>
          <lightning-button label="Cancel" data-id='foo'></lightning-button>
          <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-button-group>
      </div>
    </form>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import getOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/CommissionsController.getOpportunity';


export default class Commissions extends LightningElement {

    data = [];
    dataToShow = [];
    options = [];
    value = '';
    famOptions = [];
    famValue = 'All';
    setFmlyOpt = new Set();


    connectedCallback() {      
        this.init();
    }

    async init(){
        let dataGlobal = await getOpportunity({OpportunityId:'0063O000009SxZjQAK'});
        await this.getOptions(dataGlobal.OpportunityTeamMembers);
        this.createData(dataGlobal.OpportunityLineItems);
        this.createFamilyOpt();
    }

    getOptions(team){
        let opt = [];
        team.forEach(element =>{
            let a = {};
            a.label = element.Name;
            a.value = element.Name;
            opt.push(a);
        });
        this.options = opt; 
    }

    createData(oppLI){
        let info = [];
        oppLI.forEach(element =>{
            let a = {};
            a.Id = element.Id;
            a.Product = element.Name;
            a.Family = element.PricebookEntry.Product2.Family;
            a.Team = '';
            a.Comission = ''
            info.push(a);
            this.setFmlyOpt.add(element.PricebookEntry.Product2.Family);
        });
        this.data = info;
        this.dataToShow = this.data;
    }

    createFamilyOpt(){

        let op = [{
            label: 'All',
            value: 'All'
        }];

        for (let optFam of this.setFmlyOpt) {
            let a = {};
            a.label = optFam;
            a.value = optFam;
            op.push(a);
        }

        this.famOptions = op;
    }

    handleChangeFamily(event){

        if(event.detail.value == 'All'){
            this.dataToShow = this.data;
        }else{
            let temporal = [];
            this.data.forEach(element => {
                if(element.Family == event.detail.value){
                    temporal.push(element);
                }
            });
            this.dataToShow = temporal;
        }
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('ingresa:');
        let proxy = this.template.querySelector('[data-key="00k3O000007PA4WQAW"]');
        console.log('proxy:', proxy);      
    }

}
```

I need to return the data of tbody, so I created the method handleClick to get td tag by data-key, but the console shows me the proxy object and I do not know how to managed to get the information that I need.

[image]

I really appreciate any help,

regards.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) has this to say:

> The Proxy object enables you to create a proxy for another object, which can intercept and redefine fundamental operations for that object.

In Locker Service, most objects are returned as proxies. This is a wrapper that enforces security across namespaces and components.

The Proxy in your case is wrapped around the `tr` that you queried. You should still be able to access individual elements, such as `proxy.dataset.key`. As far as inspecting in source mode, check out the `[[Target]]`, as this shows what's inside.